# Text on a soccer jersey

Tags: text-object

How do I add flat text onto the back of a soccer jersey? The jersey itself isn't flat but I would like the text to take the shape of the back so it looks like a proper jersey like the image attached:  [ImageExample](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwj8hMa3gKvjAhUyh-AKHU4SCGUQjRx6BAgBEAQ&url=%2Furl%3Fsa%3Di%26rct%3Dj%26q%3D%26esrc%3Ds%26source%3Dimages%26cd%3D%26ved%3D%26url%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.eurogamer.net%252Farticles%252F2018-09-28-fifa-19-on-switch-is-more-than-a-reskin-even-if-it-falls-short-of-the-real-deal%26psig%3DAOvVaw3fJBiUSZ_Dqq063akmRT76%26ust%3D1562870408945249&psig=AOvVaw3fJBiUSZ_Dqq063akmRT76&ust=1562870408945249)

Comment: I wouldn't add a text object to the back, myself.  I think that is the job of an image texture.  Here's an idea though:  you could try converting the text object to a mesh and use the shrink wrap modifier to put it on the jersey.

Comment: Thanks ill try it