# Image on clothing

Tags: image

Imagine a character has a t shirt. I would like to add my logo (a JPEG file) to stick onto the jersey. What is the best method? I tried UV but it didnt work.

Comment: I think you can use the same principle as here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/61519/how-to-create-decal-from-mesh/61523#61523

Comment: You could try UV project from view

Comment: How is this different from https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/145020/text-on-a-soccer-jersey ? Please don't post the same question more than once

Comment: 1. A text is diff to an image. 2 Im not asking the same question. 3 im new to blender 4. how unwelcoming uninspriring and dam right rude do u wanna be?